# I can create only one CKEditor per web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I'm writing a web application in JavaScript, using Bootstrap. It dynamically creates several textareas, and I want to convert them to CKEditors. However, only one instance of CKEditor is created, the second 'replace' gives "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unselectable' of null". The code that creates them is very simple:

```js
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace(id);
editor.on('change', function (evt) {
  element.value = editor.getData();
});
```

The textareas are created together with some forms from some templates.

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id="[%id%]-form" name="[%id%]-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="[%id%]-input-name" class="col-md-2 control-label">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="text" size="30" class="form-control" id="[%id%]-input-name" name="projectname" readonly="readonly" value="[%state.defined.projectname%]"/>
    </div>
    <label for="[%id%]-input-name" class="col-md-2 control-label">Version:</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="text" size="30" class="form-control" id="[%id%]-input-version" name="version" readonly="readonly" value="[%state.defined.version%]"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="[%id%]-input-title" class="col-md-2 control-label">Title:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control" id="[%id%]-input-title" name="projecttitle" placeholder="Project title" value="[%state.defined.title%]"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="[%id%]-input-desc" class="col-md-2 control-label">Description:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" id="[%id%]-input-desc" name="description" placeholder="Project description">
        [%state.defined.description%]
      </textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
. . .
```

and

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id="[%id%]-form" name="[%id%]-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="[%id%]-input-title" class="col-md-2 control-label">Topic:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control" id="[%id%]-input-title" name="title" placeholder="Thread title"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="[%id%]-input-text" class="col-md-2 control-label">Text:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" id="[%id%]-input-text" name="text" placeholder="Text to post">
      </textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input type="hidden" name="forumid" value="[%state.forumid%]"/>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="[%id%]-post" value="Post"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The generated HTML is then inserted into some  area using innerHTML property. I forgot to mention that the area is collapsible (i.e. has Bootstrap's class "collapse"). Everything works fine, except that the second textarea is not replaced.

One more thing: the exception occurs not in 'replace', but a little later. Here's the stack trace:

```
b (ckeditor.js:326)
(anonymous function) (ckeditor.js:322)
j (ckeditor.js:10)
CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire (ckeditor.js:12)
CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire (ckeditor.js:13)
CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fireOnce (ckeditor.js:12)
CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fireOnce (ckeditor.js:13)
(anonymous function) (ckeditor.js:246)
CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load.g (ckeditor.js:226)
CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load (ckeditor.js:226)
(anonymous function) (ckeditor.js:245)
(anonymous function) (ckeditor.js:233)
(anonymous function) (ckeditor.js:231)
CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load.g (ckeditor.js:226)
CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load (ckeditor.js:226)
CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load (ckeditor.js:231)
h (ckeditor.js:232)
(anonymous function) (ckeditor.js:233)
g (ckeditor.js:244)
(anonymous function) (ckeditor.js:243)
(anonymous function) (ckeditor.js:468)
(anonymous function) (ckeditor.js:231)
CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load.g (ckeditor.js:226)
CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load.B (ckeditor.js:226)
CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load.s (ckeditor.js:226)
(anonymous function) (ckeditor.js:227)
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS. I've found a few things. First, it's not relevant that form #2 is created after form #1; even if I omit the first form's creation, the problem still exists. Second, the difference between them is in the way they are located in the DOM; the second form has deeper nesting, it's inside several nested divs. When I place it at the top level, it works. My question: is there any limitation on the number of nesting levels where CKEditor can be created? So far, I haven't seen any components that have a problem with that.

Comment: Could you post your complete working code

Comment: I've edited the original post to include what may be relevant.

Comment: Could you check the textareas id that is passed in the Ckeditor is available in the DOM

Comment: Make sure you have *unique* ids. No duplicates ever.

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating dynamically CKEditor instances too, but I'm using CKEditor's Jquery adapter, it is inside CKEditor folder at adapters Folder.

My code is like this:

```
var data = { id: 'some-random-id' , content: '<p>Initial Text Content</p>'};

var $element = $('#'+data.id);
  $element.on('blur', function(){
    data.content = CKEDITOR.instances[data.id].getData();         
}

//Create CKEditor instance
$element.ckeditor(function () {
  //Some Stuffs that my code does when ckeditor is created
});
```

My mustache template is like this:

```
<script id="txt" type="text/html">
   <div id="{{id}}" contenteditable="true" >
      {{& content}}
   </div>
</script>
```

An normal HTML shoud be like this:

```
<div id="some-random-id" contenteditable="true" >
   <p>Initial text content</p>
</div>
```

To remove it from page, you have to destroy with ckeditor destroy.

```
CKEDITOR.instances[data.id].destroy();
```